# Consider $T:\ell^{2}\longrightarrow \ell^{2}$ defined by $T(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n},...)=(0,0,3x_{1},2x_{2},4x_{3},3x_{4},2x_{5},4x_{6},...)$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show that this operator is continuous. For that purpose, I was trying to show the continuity at 0. That is to say, I want to show that
$\|T(x)\|\leq M \|x\|$, where $x\in \ell^{2}$ and M is some constant.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like $M=4$ would do.

Comment: And $M=4$ is best

Comment: Thanks so much. I looks like that it was  all that I needed.

Comment: Maybe do you know how to compute $\|T\|$ now?

Answer (score 0):

The best $M$ is the operator norm $\|T\|_{op}$ of $T$. It is given by
$$
\|T\|_{op} = \sup\{\|Tx\| : x\in\ell^2 \text{ with } \|x\|=1 \}.
$$
For arbitrary $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\ell^2$ we have
$$
\|Tx\|^2 = \sum_{n\in\Bbb N} |g(n)x_n|^2 \leq \sum_{n\in\Bbb N} |4x_n|^2 = 4^2 \|x\|^2
$$
with $g(n) = \begin{cases}2, & n\mod 3 = 2\\ 3, & n\mod 3 = 1\\ 4, & n\mod 3=0\end{cases}$.

Thus $\|T\|_{op} \leq 4$.

To see $\|T\|_{op} \geq 4$ we take $x=(0,0,1, 0, \ldots)$ (only one entry =1). Now $\|x\| = 1$ and
$\|Tx\| = 4$.